# Edit data before saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `bookmark` model with a `:url` attribute. I need it to be saved in database in correct format: with `http://` or `https://` prefix.

So, in `bookmarks_controller` I've made a `before_filter` for `create` action:

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :standardise_urls, only: :create
.
.
.
def create
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build(params[:bookmark])
    if @bookmark.save
      flash[:success] = "Bookmark created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
.
.
.
private

  def standardise_urls
    if params[:bookmark][:url] != /https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]+/
      params[:bookmark][:url] = "http://#{params[:bookmark][:url]}"
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. I want it to add `http://` prefix to links, which don't have it, when user add them. But it continue adding prefix to all created links.

I think the mistake is in repeating `params[:bookmark][:url]`, but I don't understand how to solve it.

Also, is it right to add this filter in controller? Maybe it must be in model level? Or maybe it is better to add prefix on the fly, when generating view, so I must put it there?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your logic is that you're testing for equality on the regular expression, rather than doing an actual regex test (=~ or !~).

I would recommend doing this in your bookmark model. It will be easier to test and it seems like the responsibility of the model to know what a valid URL is. You can do this by overriding the url setter method that is automatically generated by Active Record:

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  def url=(link)
    unless link =~ /https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]+/
      link = "http://#{link}"
    end

    super
  end
end
```